# Does a partial match break the WebApi HTTP route scanning?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I was under the impression that in MVC4 the WebApi would attempt to match the first rule, and if it was not successful then it would go on to the next rule. But in my application for some reason there is a partial match on the first rule that causes MVC4 not to attempt the second rule. Here is the example:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiByAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { action = "Get" }
        );
    }


    public class MyController: ApiController
    {
        public Boolean GetMyAction(string Param1, string Param2)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The rules above are the default rules, and I've got a GET call with this url `/api/MyController/MyAction?Param1=xxx&Param2=yyy`. This is matching the first rule since id is optional, and the parameter plus request method (GET) are also the same as the controller action. But if I flip the two rules around, I don't get a match anymore.

I get an error `No action was found on the controller MyController that matches the name "MyAction"`. In the controller my action name is `GetMyAction`, so it makes sense that it won't match. But why won't it go to the next rule, which I know will match?

On the flip side of this problem I do have other controllers with multiple GET actions and no parameters. So in order to not get a multiple match error on the `DefaultApi` rule I need to match by name first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the [routing and action selection web page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection). The page gives the following phases for routing:

1. Matching the URI to a route template.
2. Selecting a controller.
3. Selecting an action.

It is not absolutely explicit for my taste. But I understand that the matching phase only applies to the route template string. Finding a matching controller and action are not part of finding the actual routing rule to be used. It would be possible to lookup for the next matching route string, if no action/controller is found. But that is not how it was implemented. If we look at the rule as a whole, a partial match will interrupt the matching process by design.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the most specific route to the most generic route, just as we do with exceptions in `try/catch` blocks.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{

     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "ApiByAction",
         routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
         defaults: new { action = "Get" }
     );

     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "DefaultApi",
         routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/MyAction",
         defaults: new { action = "MyAction" }
     );

     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "DefaultApi",
         routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
         defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
     );

}
```

With this, the asp.net web api will find for the first one, and get it working fine, if not, will find using the second pattern.

Comment: When I make this change and try /api/MyController/MyAction?Param1=xxx&Param2=yyy, I get an "No action was found on the controller 'MyController' that matches the name 'MyAction'" error.

Comment: You do not have a `GetMyAction` action method in the web api, it will not work, if you want to add a route for this, you have to add a new custom route, look my edit.